# Why does need setting target membership ios

Tags: ios

Please tell me why I have to set target membership

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Very briefly --- you have multiple *targets* in your Xcode project. Some files will NOT be used in all targets.

So, when you add / create a new file, you have to tell Xcode which targets will be using that file.